How can a citation dataset (like Cora) have strongly connected components?
This website https://snap.stanford.edu/data/cit-HepPh.html shows that the High-energy physics citation network has strongly connected components and it's driving me crazy.
A SCC would mean that you can find a path from a paper x to a paper y. This means the following: if a paper x in 2023 cites a paper y written in 2018, you can find a path of papers a0, ..., ak such that y cites a0, a0 cites a1, ...., ak-1 cites ak, and ak, cites y, which is a contradiction because a paper can only cite papers written before it. How can that be possible????

As a practical matter, it's not uncommon for an author of paper A to cite a paper B that is in preparation and also have the author of paper B cite paper A.  This can happen because of the widespread availability of preprints.

Leskovec
et al. carefully define their terms in §3.2:

two nodes in an undirected network
are connected if there is a path between them


All of our graphs
have a single giant component – a connected component (or
weakly connected component in the case of directed graphs,
ignoring the direction of the edges) that accounts for a significant fraction of all nodes.

There is no conflict of the sort you propose.

The first definition pertains to an undirected graph, and the second points talks about weakly connected components, but there is no mention of strongly connected components

Their "connected component" is SCC, and "weakly connected component" is WCC. If you're unhappy with the paper's conclusions, it appears that Jure Leskovec is the corresponding author.
